# Frage nach zwei Relativsätze und die Benutzung von “selbst”

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, relative-clause

Hier ist der Kontext:

> Ich erinnere mich, es war der Sechstagekrieg und als Folge meiner radikal an mir vorgenommenen Cortisonbehandlung entwickelte sich mein Mondgesicht, wie von den Ärzten gewünscht; während der Visite kommentierten sie dieses Mondgesicht auf ihre witzige Art, **die selbst mich**, **der** ich, nach ihrer eigenen Aussage, nur noch Wochen, im besten Fall Monate zu leben hatte, zum Lachen brachte. (Quelle: *Wittgensteins Neffe*, Thomas Bernhard)

1. Ich verstehe nicht, was *„die selbst mich“* bedeutet.
2. Worauf bezieht sich *„selbst“*?
3. *deleted*
4. Worauf bezieht sich *„der“*?

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort *»selbst«* in diesem Kontext ein Fokuspartikel und kann durch *»sogar«* oder *»auch«* ersetzt werden.

Das Wort *»der«* ist hier ein Relativpronomen, das einen Relativsatz einleitet. Es kann durch *»welcher«* ersetzt werden. Der ganze Relativsatz (»der ich, nach ihrer eigenen Aussage, nur noch Wochen, im besten Fall Monate zu leben hatte«) bezieht sich auf das unmittelbar davor stehende Wort *»mich«.*

> Die Ärzte kommentierten mein Mondgesicht auf ihre witzige Art, die **selbst** mich, **der** ich nur noch Wochen zu leben hatte, zum Lachen brachte.
>
> Die Ärzte kommentierten mein Mondgesicht auf ihre witzige Art, die **sogar** mich, **welcher** ich nur noch Wochen zu leben hatte, zum Lachen brachte.
> Die Ärzte kommentierten mein Mondgesicht auf ihre witzige Art, die **auch** mich, **welcher** ich nur noch Wochen zu leben hatte, zum Lachen brachte.

---

Ich verstehe die Frage 3 nicht. Es wurden keine Verben weggelassen.